# Springboot application.yml fallback to other section in single file

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I have a single `application.yml` with the first section unlabeled for defaults, then the usual sections for development, qa, prod.
The first section works correctly as defaults, and then the selected profile
(With -Dspring.profiles.active=development style command line) works correctly.

What I want to do is in a named section such as

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: rkeene
```

I want to then say for it to fallback to developer, and then back to the defaults.
I have looked quite a bit and can't find this exact use case.
Maybe like:

```
spring:
  config:
  activate:
    on-profile: rkeene
  include: developer
```

So I get the developer profile and then override just a very few settings.
All in a single application.yml file.

How is this done?